# Add phone number to Zelle using email

Tags: money-transfer

I have a Zelle account tied to one of my email accounts. Someone sent a Zelle payment to my cell phone number.

Can I add that as a second way to get funds directed to me or, alternatively can I switch it to that phone number instead of email and if I do so what bad things can happen?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't asking Zelle this question?

Comment: Is this off-topic here ?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite This is on-topic, in my opinion. It is certainly related to personal finance, not too broad, not primarily opinion-based, not asking for product recommendations.

Comment: I put it into "please tell us what you've already tried." No objection to helping people, but I want to help teach them to help themselves so I want to see evidence of some effort. And asking the right people probably gets the best answer fastest. Having said that...

Comment: +1, on-topic, and these downvotes are not a great way to welcome new users.

Comment: It’s actually my wife’s account and I didn’t feel comfortable suggesting she fooled with it unless there was a reasonable prospect of it not getting screwed up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have both an e-mail address and a mobile phone number tied to the same bank account using Zelle. I have my checking account set up this way with Zelle through my credit union’s mobile app.

However, this is something that might be limited by your bank’s policy or mobile app features. If you are having trouble figuring it out, contact your bank.